# How to get element from a list of interface implementations by implementation name

Tags: java, generics

I have a list of implementations to `SomeInterface`

```
List<SomeInterface> listOfThingsThatImplementsSomeInterface
```

I want to extract a specific implementation from the list according to its class name

```
private SomeInterface getThisType(SomeInterfaceImpl myType) {
    SomeInterfaceImpl impl = null
    for (SomeInterface current: listOfThingsThatImplementsSomeInterface) {
        if (current instanceof myType) {
            impl = current
            break;
        }
    }
    return impl;
}
```

Is that possible in Java? should I be using generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have the desired implementation `Class` instance, (refer to [@f1sh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71751970/how-to-get-element-from-a-list-of-interface-implementations-by-implementation-na/#answer-71752104) if the class is `Class<?>`), it can be done using Stream,

```java
private <T extends SomeInterface> Optional<T> getThisType(Class<T> type) {
    return this.someInterfaceList.stream().filter(type::isInstance)
            .map(type::cast).findFirst();
}
```

The key to match the type is using [`Class#isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)).
Some points to note:

1. Make method return type generic so no cast is needed.
2. [`Class#cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)) can be used to convert the return type of the Stream.
3. Use `Optional` to handle case when no element matched.

---

Full example

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class FilterByClass {

    List<SomeInterface> someInterfaceList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FilterByClass filterByClass = new FilterByClass();
        filterByClass.someInterfaceList = List.of(new SomeInterfaceImplA(), new SomeInterfaceImplB(), new SomeInterfaceImplC());
        System.out.println(filterByClass.getThisType(SomeInterfaceImplA.class).get().name());
        System.out.println(filterByClass.getThisType(SomeInterfaceImplB.class).get().name());
        System.out.println(filterByClass.getThisType(SomeInterfaceImplC.class).get().name());
    }

    private <T extends SomeInterface> Optional<T> getThisType(Class<T> type) {
        return this.someInterfaceList.stream().filter(type::isInstance)
                .map(type::cast).findFirst();
    }

    public interface SomeInterface {
        default String name() {
            return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        }
    }

    public static class SomeInterfaceImplA implements SomeInterface { }

    public static class SomeInterfaceImplB implements SomeInterface { }

    public static class SomeInterfaceImplC implements SomeInterface { }
}
```

Comment: Consider using `type::isInstance` instead of `element -> type.isInstance(element)`.

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn, good suggestion, updated.

Answer (score 2):

First you need the `Class` instance of the desired class (which you have, you mention "according to its class name"). You can get a `Class` instance from the class name using

```
Class<?> cls = SomeInterfaceImpl.class;
```

or if you have the class name as a String:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("package.ClassName")
```

or from an instance using

```
SomeInterfaceImpl myType = ...;
Class<?> cls = myType.getClass()
```

Then you can call this method, assuming your have a `List<SomeInterface> listOfThingsThatImplementsSomeInterface` somewhere:

```
private SomeInterface getThisType(Class<?> myType) {
    for (SomeInterface current: listOfThingsThatImplementsSomeInterface) {
        if (myType.isInstance(current)) {
            return current;
        }
    }
    return null; //nothing found
}
```

Comment: just tested it `Class.forName("package.ClassName")` will not work inside `myType.isInstance(current)`

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos how did you try that? https://ideone.com/1KW1hl proves that it works

Comment: looking better maybe your answer is what he expects, only OP can answer for sure

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos I think it's debatable that the input is actually a `String`. But just to prove that this also works: https://ideone.com/1KW1hl The `Class.forName` is just another way to get the `Class` instance.

Comment: And of course this can also be done with streams, but the interesting part here was to show the usage of the `isInstance` method.

Comment: agree the answer has proved the main topic of `isInstance` and is a very interesting one

Answer (score 1):

The method should take the class as parameter. Let's say your interface is `T`, you can receive a parameter of type `Class<? extends T>`

Then go through the list and check for an element with the same class

Here is an example that should work:

```
private static <T> Optional<T> getThisType(
        List<T> listOfThingsThatImplementsInterfaceT, 
        Class<? extends T> klass) {
    return listOfThingsThatImplementsInterfaceT.stream()
            .filter(klass::isInstance)
            .findFirst();
}
```

Test with a list of `Serializable`

```
List<Serializable> listOfThingsThatImplementsSerializable = Arrays.asList(
    new Integer(1), new Float(2), new Double(3)
);

System.out.println(
    getThisType(listOfThingsThatImplementsSerializable, Float.class)
);
```

Looking for the `Float` returns `Optional[2.0]`